# gandi api call from C# returns 400. Its Working Fine from Postman

Tags: c#, json

I have create gandi api code for create domain and for that i have write below code, but it show me 400 bad request error

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<JsonResult> InsertDomain(DomainDetails domainDetails)
{
  HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
  try
  {
    var url = "https://api.gandi.net/v5/domain/domains";

    using ( var client = new HttpClient() )
    {
      var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(domainDetails);
      HttpContent HttpContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
      var MyHttpClient = new HttpClient();
      MyHttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("authorization", GANDI_API_Key);
      response = await MyHttpClient.PostAsync(url, HttpContent);
    }
  }
  catch ( Exception ex )
  {
    throw;
  }
  return Json(new { result = response }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);     
}
```

but when i try to pass same data using postman then it's working fine below code is my postman data

```
Body
{
  "fqdn":"dedasdom1906.com",
  "owner":
    {
      "city":"Paris",
      "given":"Alice",
      "family":"Doe",
      "zip":"75001",
      "country":"FR",
      "streetaddr":"5 rue neuve",
      "phone":"+33.123456789",
      "state":"FR-J",
      "type":"0",
      "email":"alice@example.org"
      }
}

Header
authorization : Apikey
Content-Type : application/json
```

Comment: Just a question, why are you creating a new client inside a using statement with a HttpClient? Probably isn't your problem, but something that is worth pointing out...

Comment: It's a little confusing you've got a variable of type HttpContent with the name HttpContent also

Answer (score 1):

1. I havent worked with this endpoint, but you are missing the return type.
2. the next thing i would try is to paste json string directly in the StringContent.
3. please paste the correct string content(rename the variable)

if none of this help you, please give more details.

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
```

Answer (score 0):

For the `https://api.gandi.net/v5/domain/domains` endpoint, use HTTP `GET` ([`HttpClient.GetAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8)) to retrieve a list of your domains. Use HTTP `POST` (`HttpClient.PostAsync`) to create a new domain.

If you're trying to `POST` JSON, I would use the `PostAsJsonAsync` method, [example here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client):

```
static async Task<Uri> CreateProductAsync(Product product)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(
        "api/products", product);
         ...
```

Also note your auth header needs to start with "apikey" though it looks like you have that working. Curl example:

```
curl -X GET \
  https://api.gandi.net/v5/domain/domains \
  -H 'authorization: Apikey your-api-key'
```

https://api.gandi.net/docs/domains/